# Multiple targets sharing common files in an Xcode project

Tags: xcode

I would like to ask you guys what is the logic behind this:

When you create an app on Xcode 4, it creates a group with the same name of your app and put the delegate and viewController files inside it. It also puts all other files, including main.m and -prefix.pch inside a folder called Supporting Files.

If you create another target, it creates a similar structure for the other target. Now you have two AppDelegate files, two main.m files, two of everything what would be nice to maintain. I have a project with 4 targets, so in theory I would have 4 of everything, what is stupid.

In fantastic Xcode 3, you had just the needed files for multiple targets, not this mess. You had a directory Classes, where all classes were put. Just one copy.

If you try to rename the groups and moving files around to create a sane structure, you end dealing with hours and hours of troubles as files that don't compile, missing paths, and stuff like that.

I simply don't understand how this is better than what we have in Xcode 3.

Can someone explain this insanity?

Comment: thanks for down voting a question just because I expressed my opinion about Xcode 4. Yes, Xcode 4 stinks and this is the truth. It crashes if you move files, it crashes if rename files, it crashes if you copy files, it crashes if you blink, it creates illogical structures, it lacks a lot of functionality Xcode 3 had, it has a micro debugger window (yes, I know how to expand it, but it stinks having to do that too). I have 20 Xcode crashes every 4 hours working with it and I had 0 crashes with Xcode 3, so Xcode 4 stinks infinity +1.

Comment: You were probably down voted for lack of proof reading. I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and trust that English is not your first language. I went ahead and upvoted you the get you to neutral. I would suggest that you not address communities when you are angry. I know when I do it, I come across as a jerk.

Comment: thanks. English is not my natural language. Voted down because my english is bad? This is amazing. Just a moron would do that. I try to express myself in english, but sometimes it is difficult to express some ideas, as english is written backwards and simplified most part of time, compared to my language. So, I have to reorder the phrases in my head and sometimes the result is weird, but I try. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you need to move files around. In my case with 2 targets project. I have 2 groups with same name of target which was created by Xcode. and I have a Common Group to place all the necessary files that shared by both targets(make sure this files' target membership pointed to both targets)

And you can duplicate a target to avoid configure similar settings again.

Comment: @RubberDuck
`make sure this files' target membership pointed to both targets` how do i do this?

Comment: @VaibhavSaran Select the file and check the desired Target Membership in  the `File inspector`.